# Can I prevent Strapi on Google App Engine from going to Sleep

Tags: nginx, google-app-engine, strapi

I am hosting Strapi the headless CMS on Google App Engine and my issue is that this backend goes to sleep after some inactivity, and due to this it requires waking up when it is interacted with, resulting in a good few seconds passing by before any API calls are retrieved.

I can see on Google App Engine the logs show that the app is starting, then the network stuff happens and so on until nginx is started and then a welcome back message is stated before the API call can be seen.

Does anyone know how I can keep this running continuously without having it sleep…perhaps pinging is an option but I was hoping for a setting/config that would allow this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Guide](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/hosting-guides/google-app-engine.html) for creating a strapi project on App Engine.

As mentioned in the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/configuring-warmup-requests) :

> Warmup requests are used by the App Engine scheduler, which controls
> the auto scaling of instances based on user-supplied configuration.
> With warmup requests enabled, App Engine issues GET requests to
> /_ah/warm up. You can implement handlers for this request to perform
> application-specific tasks, such as pre-caching application data.
>
> The scheduler starts up instances when it determines that more
> instances are needed. Warmup requests may appear in logs even if they
> are disabled because the scheduler uses them to start instances.
>
> For example, if you are using Express.js, your handler might look
> like:
>
> ```
> const express = require('express');
> const app = express();
>
> app.get('/_ah/warmup', (req, res) => {
>     // Handle your warmup logic. Initiate db connection, etc.
> });
>
> // Rest of your application handlers.
> app.get('/', handler);
> app.listen(8080);
> ```

You can also refer  [the forum](https://forum.strapi.io/t/strapi-automatic-scaling-on-google-app-engine/17688) for more information related to strapi automatic scaling on App Engine.

For more information, you can refer to the [Documentation_1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/how-instances-are-managed) and [Documentation_2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/how-requests-are-handled#handling_requests) to know how instances are managed and requests have been handled on App engine.

Comment: Perfect, thank you Divyani, really appreciate it.

Comment: @Shahinoor Rahman is posted answer helpful?

Comment: I have not had time to test this out, but have read through the information, I believe this should be helpful but am yet to test this out.